# How to check if a string is a Google Click ID (GCLID) in PHP?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

This is a valid Google Click ID string:

```
CP7os5-UmcYCFasEwwodNIUA2A
```

This is also a valid Google Click ID string:

```
CjwKEAjw2ImsBRCnjq70n_amv14SJAChXijNyDh6_0YQL6aGJXdU6NsrseN9FSJomlqmSm4BNHqFBxoCZrvw_wcB
```

This is a random string, and probably this is not a valid Google Click ID string:

```
xjjdhdjskdjsdosidos43242342
```

Does anyone know how to detect if a string is a valid GCLID in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to check if a string is a valid `GCLID` in `PHP` because it contains a timestamp, and two other different integers.

But you can certainly decode it using this useful function provided by this [Blog here](https://deedpolloffice.com/blog/articles/decoding-gclid-parameter)